# What is a Python equivalent function for the R code below, mostly for tail(F0, n-1)?

Tags: python, r

R-code:

function (scores, classes, p0 = 0.55 , p1= 0.1, ROI = 0.2644)

{

roc= .empROCInfo(scores,classes)

alpha <- 1- p0 - p1

lambda <- c(0, (roc$pi1 * ROI/roc$pi0)* diff(roc$F1)/diff(roc$F0)

lambda <- c(lambda[lambda < 1], 1)

lambdaie <- tail(lambda, n=-1)

lambdaii <- head(lambda, n=-1)

F0 <- roc$F0[1:length(lambdaii)]

F1 <- roc$F1[1:length(lambdaii)]

EMPC <- sum(alpha * lambdaie - lambdaii) * (roc$pi0 * F0 * (lambdaie + lambdaii)/2 - ROI * F1 * roc$pi1)) + (roc$pi0 * tail(F0, n-1) - ROI * roc$pi1 * tail(F1, n-1)) * p1

}

Comment: `F0[1:]` is the equivalent of `tail(F0, n = -1)` the rest you can do. Whe you ask a question. Ask one question at a time. Also Note that this is not a code translation site. You should google how to do each line and translate the code by yourself

Comment: Hi thank you for your response! I understand and will ask on a different manner next time! However I noticed you gave an equivalent of tail(FO, n = -1) but I would like to know the equivalent of tail(F0, n-1)… Is the response different for this?

Comment: `tail(F0, n-1)` means get the last `n-1` elements which is equivalent to `F0[n-1:]` what is the class of `F0` is R and what is the class of F0 is python? Those are the questions yo need to ask yourself because if in python F0 is a pandas DataFrame, then you could use the `.tail` method